# What size to create System Center DPM client protection disk storage allocation?

Tags: scdpm

We're using Microsoft System Center Data Protection Manager (DPM 2019) to back up our client data. When creating a protection group with clients, DPM asks how much data each computer will be backing up so it can allocate disk space for each of them.

[image: data per computer]

The struggle is that it's not a one-size-fits-all situation. I have some clients with < 1GB and some with > 500GB. If the "Data per computer" is set to 5GB, they allocate 7.61GB of storage for that client (as seen in the picture above). Here's my questions.

1. Will clients using less than the allocated amount hold backup space
   that they will never use? (eg. client has 1GB data and reserve
   7.61GB....is 6.61GB of backup space allocated in waste?)
2. Will clients over the allocation space still backup fine? Will DPM
   just expand their allocation as needed and work without a problem?
   (eg. client has 60GB and allocated only 7.61GB when setting up the
   protection group)

I've been unable to find a clear answer to this on the web. I'm trying to determine if I need to have different protection groups based on client data size. Really hoping not....

Thanks!